# how to look at debugging error in android.(eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Hi friends i am new for android application..how to check debugging errors in android(eclipse)
please help me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the debugging details from the Logcat.
Just open Window-->Open Perspective-->DDMS
then
again open Window-->Show View-->LogCat

Answer (score 0):

I prefer reading the stack tree from logcat.

You open the logcat tab by doing:

Window -> Show View -> Other -> LogCat (from the list).

When you have the logcat up, you can click on the circle with a red E in the middle in the window's top right corner. This will filter the logcat messages to only show error messages.

But be warned, some stack trees give you incorrect information sometimes(example: last night, I had a nullpointerexception thrown because a thread hadn't initiated something. It referred me to a code-comment...). But I'm not whining, logcat is great!